# Laggy WCSession sendMessageData

Tags: ios, watchos, core-motion, watchconnectivity

I am polling the apple watch for Core Motion at a frequency of 0.01. The purpose of the application is to see movement in real-time. To capture data as quickly as possible, I leverage the didReceiveMessageData/ sendMessageData functions. On the iPhone, I have a simple function that reads the data:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data) {
    let records : [Double] = try! NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self], from: messageData) as! [Double]
}
```

And on an Apple Watch 6, I have a simple function that sends the data. However, sending suffers from a sporadic yet significant delay.

```
class MyController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {
    
    private let motion = CMMotionManager()
    private let motionQueue = OperationQueue()
    private let messagingQueue = OperationQueue()
    private let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    private var stack : QuaternionStack = QuaternionStack()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    
        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default
            session.delegate = self
            if session.activationState == .notActivated { session.activate() }
        }
    
        // Serial queue for sample handling and calculations.
        messagingQueue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        messagingQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        motionQueue.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        motionQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

        startGettingData();
    }

    func startGettingData() {
    
        // If we have already started the workout, then do nothing.
        if (workoutSession != nil) { return }
        if !motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable { return }
    
        let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
        workoutConfiguration.activityType = .functionalStrengthTraining
        workoutConfiguration.locationType = .indoor
    
        do {
            workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: workoutConfiguration)
        } catch { fatalError("Unable to create the workout session!") }
    
        // Start the workout session and device motion updates.
        workoutSession!.startActivity(with: Date())
        motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
        motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xArbitraryZVertical, to: motionQueue) { [self] (deviceMotion: CMDeviceMotion?, _ : Error?) in
            guard let motion = deviceMotion else { return }
            let attitude = motion.attitude.quaternion
            stack.push(Quaternion(x: attitude.x, y: attitude.y, z: attitude.z, w: attitude.w))
            guard let quaternions = stack.pop() else { return }
        
            messagingQueue.cancelAllOperations()
            let blockOperation = BlockOperation()
            blockOperation.addExecutionBlock({ [unowned blockOperation] in
                if blockOperation.isCancelled { return }
                self.sendDataToPhone(quaternions: quaternions)
            })
            messagingQueue.addOperation(blockOperation)
        }
    }

    private func sendDataToPhone(quaternions: [Quaternion]) {
        if WCSession.default.isReachable {
            var capturedQuaternions : [Double] = [Double]()
            for quat in quaternions { capturedQuaternions.append(contentsOf: [quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w]) }
            WCSession.default.sendMessageData(try! NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: capturedQuaternions, requiringSecureCoding: false), replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil);
        }
    }

}
```

I've implemented a stack as follows:

```
struct QuaternionStack {

    private let max = 2;
    private var array: [Quaternion] = []

    mutating func push(_ element: Quaternion) {
        array.append(element)
        if array.count > max { array.removeFirst() }
    }

    mutating func pop() -> [Quaternion]? {
        if (array.count < max) { return nil }
        var results : [Quaternion] = [Quaternion]()
        for _ in 0 ..< max { results.append(array.popLast()!)}
        results.reverse()
        array.removeAll()
        return results
    }
}
```

If I set QuaternionStack.max to a big number, like 10, I see no obvious throttling on the iPhone when receiving data. This is because I send more data but less often. However, decreasing the number degrades the performance. As an example, imagine I send every 2 incoming packets ( QuaternionStack.max = 2 ). Sometimes, a few seconds pass between when the packets are received. When this happens, the iWatch seems to send them very quickly in an effort to catch up. Another example of this issue is when listening to music on paired Apple Airpods or receiving an incoming call. The WCSession sendMessageData from the watch becomes very inconsistent.

What must I do to increase the throughput of the WCSession sendMessageData ? The application I am writing requires very fast ( 100hz ) and continuous motion updates.